# pyright: Using TypeVar in homogeneous List with min/max

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, type-annotation, pyright

I try to understand how to use `TypeVar` with pyright.

I've built the following small function:

```py
import random
from typing import List, Sequence, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", int, str, float)
TypedList = List[T]


def merge(a: TypedList, b: TypedList) -> TypedList:
    i0, i1 = 0, 0
    merged = []

    # Run with two pointers
    while i0 < len(a) and i1 < len(b):
        merged.append(min(a[i0], b[i1]))
        if merged[-1] == a[i0]:
            i0 += 1
        else:
            i1 += 1

    # Add the tail
    if i0 >= len(a):
        merged.extend(b[i1:])
    if i1 >= len(b):
        merged.extend(a[i0:])

    return merged
```

It make pyright complain on line:

> ```
>     merged.append(min(a[i0], b[i1]))
> ```

Because:

> No overloads for "min" match the provided arguments
>
> Argument types: (TypedList[int], TypedList[int])
>
> [Pyright: reportGeneralTypeIssues]

Also, it complains on:

```
if merged[-1] == a[i0]
```

Because:

> Expected class type but received "int"

and:

> Illegal type annotation: variable not allowed unless it is a type alias

mypy seems to work fine with this line.
Any ideas about what is the problem and how I might be able to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use 'Union' instead of 'TypeVar'

```
import random
from typing import List, Sequence, TypeVar, Union


U = Union[int, str, float]
TypedList = List[U]


def merge(a: TypedList, b: TypedList) -> TypedList:
    i0, i1 = 0, 0
    merged = []

    # Run with two pointers
    while i0 < len(a) and i1 < len(b):
        merged.append(min(a[i0], b[i1]))
        if merged[-1] == a[i0]:
            i0 += 1
        else:
            i1 += 1

    # Add the tail
    if i0 >= len(a):
        merged.extend(b[i1:])
    if i1 >= len(b):
        merged.extend(a[i0:])

    return merged
```

In use of 'TypeVar', like 'T = TypeVar(...)', all T should be the same type. So, pyright has confused. In this situation, you should use 'Union' because 'U' is not necessarily the same type.

or like this

```
import random
from typing import List, Sequence, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T", int, str, float)


def merge(a: list[T], b: list[T]) -> list[T]:
    i0, i1 = 0, 0
    merged = []

    # Run with two pointers
    while i0 < len(a) and i1 < len(b):
        merged.append(min(a[i0], b[i1]))
        if merged[-1] == a[i0]:
            i0 += 1
        else:
            i1 += 1

    # Add the tail
    if i0 >= len(a):
        merged.extend(b[i1:])
    if i1 >= len(b):
        merged.extend(a[i0:])

    return merged
```